# Quesition about permissions on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I know it should be easy question but still facing an issue with permissions.
I need to have 3 users in postgres:

1. Fully Admin like default "postgres" user
2. Should have access to insert, select and update with delete but no admin access
3. Should have access to all tables only with read only permissions

I did this in this way:

```
CREATE role program_schema_role_ro ;
CREATE role program_schema_role_normal ;
CREATE role program_schema_role_admin ;

CREATE USER user_ro WITH PASSWORD 'user_ro';
CREATE USER user_app WITH PASSWORD 'user_app';
CREATE USER user_admin WITH PASSWORD 'user_admin';

GRANT program_schema_role_ro to user_ro;
GRANT program_schema_role_normal TO user_app;
GRANT program_schema_role_admin TO user_admin;

GRANT program_schema_role_admin TO postgres;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_admin IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO program_schema_role_admin;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_admin;
GRANT posgtres TO program_schema_role_admin;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_admin GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO program_schema_role_admin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_admin;
REVOKE program_schema_role_admin FROM postgres;

GRANT program_schema_role_normal TO postgres;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_normal IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO program_schema_role_normal;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_normal;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_normal GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO program_schema_role_normal;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_normal;
REVOKE program_schema_role_normal FROM postgres;

GRANT program_schema_role_ro TO postgres;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_ro IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO program_schema_role_ro;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_ro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE program_schema_role_ro GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO program_schema_role_ro;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO program_schema_role_ro;
REVOKE program_schema_role_ro FROM postgres;
```

But still after all of this I facing a lot of issues.

Like after new table which created by admin, no read access to other
Or app user or ro user have permissions to alter.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements you run will only affect objects created by `program_schema_role_ro` itself, **not** objects created by members of that role.

You'd have to run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user_admin ...
```